# Как удалить 1 табуляцию из xml?

Tags: python, xml

Всем привет. Есть исходная xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Body>
    <object>
        <color>0</color>
        <razmer>
            <size x="0.1" y="0.1" z="0.1" />
        </razmer>
    </object>
</Body>
```

Задача удалить строку, где есть size целиком. Удаляю функцией

```
def delete_node(xml):
    tree = ElementTree()
    tree.parse(xml)
    file = tree.findall('object')
    for node in file:
        razmer = node.findall('razmer')
        for subnode in razmer:
            sizes = subnode.findall('size')
            for size in sizes:
                subnode.remove(size)
    tree.write(xml, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
delete_node('123.xml')
```

В итоге имею вот такую xml. Проблема в том, что в верхней части должны остаться двойные кавычки и появляется лишняя табуляция. Как с этим бороться, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Body>
    <object>
        <color>0</color>
        <razmer>
            </razmer>
    </object>
</Body>
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: А почему именно это проблема? С точки зрения XML всё правильно.

Comment: версия питона 2.7.3. 
С точки зрения xml - да, но нужна жесткая структура, потому что потом это обрабатывается другим кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лишняя табуляция и перевод коретки получается потому, что она есть в тексте исходного элемета subnode. Если в razmer были бы еще элементы кроме size, то после удаления size было бы все красиво. В данном случае нужно проверять сколько элементов в razmer еще осталось, после удаления всех size, и если осталось 0, то убрать текст из subnode `subnode.text=''`.

Насчет кавычек. Видимо такая шапка жестко прописана в методе write. Я бы посоветовал сохранять xml самостоятельно если это так критично. Что то вроде:

```
root=tree.getroot()
s = ElementTree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8')[38:]
xml_head = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n'
out = '%s%s' %(xml_head, s)
with open('out.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: вот этот вариант подходит лучше всего. Попробую его проверить на досуге.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не надо делать никаких манипуляций с этим xml файлом, т.е. его можно воспринимать как обычный текстовой файл — то и воспринимайте его как текстовой файл.
А в текстовом файле найти(и заменить на пустую строку) то что вам надо можно например регулярным выражением:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'<size\s.+\/>')
p.sub("", test_str)
```

Comment: Ага, а комментарии? А конструкции типа `<size></size>`? Парсить XML регулярками — плохая идея.

Comment: @VladD, Именно поэтому я и написал «обычный текстовой файл». А пограничные ситуации легко допиливаются доп. заменами. Так-то я полностью согласен, что «парсить» XML файл регулярками — абсолютное зло, но тут «парсинга» никакого нет — есть замена в строке.

Comment: Тогда проблема в том, что файл-то на самом деле XML. Так что простое решение является хрупким — при малейшем изменении подробностей сериализации (например, минификатор свернёт весь файл в одну строку) код перестанет работать правильно.

Answer (score -1):

Есть не очень красивая возможность штатными способами

```
xml_string = ElementTree.tostring(tree.getroot(), 'utf-8')
new_parsed_xml = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
pretty_string = new_parsed_xml.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
```

Comment: Пробовал похожий вариант, но желаемого эффекта не достиг(